# X-editable: close editing area on validation failure

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

***What I have:***

Multiple comments in some page. Each user can modify all his comments.

```
$.each(comments, function() {
    this.editable({
        type: 'textarea',
        mode: 'inline',
        onblur: 'submit',
        showbuttons: false,
        inputclass: 'edit-comments-text-input',
        validate: function(value) {
            if (!value.trim()) {
                return 'Can not be empty!'; //DON'T CLOSE THE EDITABLE AREA!!!
            }
        },
        success: function(response, newValue){        
            comment.text = newValue.trim();

    });
});
```

***What a problem:***

If user input an empty string, validation fails. BUT the editable area won't be closed, so user can move on and edit the next comment, with still open editing area for the previous.

***Question:***

*How to close editing text area on validation failure?*

Comment: I need to do exactly this too. Did anyone ever crack it?

Comment: @NichOverend I do not remember what was my solution. Too far ago, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I read some source code, and I got it sorted.

The important line is:

```
$('.editable-open').editableContainer('hide', 'cancel');
```

so in the example above this would be:

```
$.each(comments, function() {
    this.editable({
        type: 'textarea',
        mode: 'inline',
        onblur: 'submit',
        showbuttons: false,
        inputclass: 'edit-comments-text-input',
        validate: function(value) {
            if (!value.trim()) {
                $('.editable-open').editableContainer('hide', 'cancel');
                return 'Can not be empty!'; //DOES NOW CLOSE THE EDITABLE AREA!!!
            }
        },
        success: function(response, newValue){        
            comment.text = newValue.trim();

    });
});
```